# VPC error when trying to deploy Lambda function via Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, amazon-efs

I'm using Serverless to set up a Lambda function that gets triggered when an object is uploaded to an S3 bucket. I want that Lambda function to download the uploaded file from S3 to EFS. When I try to deploy the following `severless.yml` file, I get the error: `Function "cfnTrigger": when using fileSystemConfig, ensure that function has vpc configured on function or provider level`.

I've tried defining the `Vpc` both globally and within the Lambda function sections of the template, but both yield the same error. Also, the actual Security Groups I list within the `Vpc` represent the set of Security Groups allocated to the EFS resource and the EC2 instance to which it's attached. Both resources are also in the same Subnet that I list in the template.

Any thoughts?

**serverless.yml**:

```
service: cfn-trigger-test
frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: dev
  region: us-west-2
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-XXXXXXXXXX
      - sg-XXXXXXXXXX
      - sg-XXXXXXXXXX
    subnetdIds:
      - subnet-XXXXXXXX


functions:
  cfnTrigger:
    handler: handler.download_files_to_efs
    description: Lambda to download S3 file to EFS folder.
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: cfn-trigger-test
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          existing: true
    fileSystemConfig:
      localMountPath: /mnt/efs
      arn: arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:us-west-2:XXXXXXX:access-point/fsap-XXXXX
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - states:*
        Resource: "*"
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
        - elasticfilesystem:ClientMount
        - elasticfilesystem:ClientWrite
        - elasticfilesystem:ClientRootAccess
        Resource:
        - arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:us-west-2:XXXXXXXX:file-system/fs-XXXXXX

plugins:
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function

package:
  individually: true
  exclude:
    - '**/*'
  include:
    - handler.py
```

Comment: https://forum.serverless.com/t/lambda-deploy-into-vpc/5829/6. Is it a typo "subnetdIds" under "vpc"?

Comment: Yes, turns out that was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in next block:

```
subnetdIds:
  - subnet-XXXXXXXX
```

It must be **subnetIds** instead:

```
subnetIds:
  - subnet-XXXXXXXX
```

[Reference](https://forum.serverless.com/t/lambda-deploy-into-vpc/5829)